# OpenOCD: flash write_image only after flash erase_sector

Tags: arm, stm32f4discovery, openocd

I am playing with [STM32F4DISCOVERY](http://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/stm32f4discovery.html) kit.
I am loading  a simple "blink led" program from [jeremyherbert](https://github.com/jeremyherbert/stm32-templates/blob/master/stm32f4-discovery/src/main.c). I managed to compile the code and load it with [OpenOCD](http://openocd.org/doc/html/Flash-Commands.html). I loaded the code [with the following command](http://pulkomandy.tk/_/_Electronique/_Discovering%20the%20STM32F3%20Discovery):

```
flash write_image main.bin 0x08000000
```

The program loads and runs after resetting the board. However, `write_image` command works only after I erase flash with:

```
flash erase_sector 0 0 11
```

If I do not erase flash, even if I do `write_image` with success, the program won't run (the leds won't blink).

Question: Why do I need to `erase_sector` before writing image? Why `write_image` alone is not enough?

Comment: look at the help for write_image I think there is an erase option.  write writes, erase erases, if you want to write you need to erase first.

Comment: Thanks. But why overwriting flash with write_image is not enough? If "erase" is necessary, why it is even an option (and not a default behavior)? It is not that "write" writes ones, and "erase" writes zeros :)

Comment: depends on the part more often an erase clears it to ones, and a write writes the zeros if you want to think about that.  But if a byte had the value 0xA from the last write and now you want that byte to be a 0x4 and write a 0x4 that by stays an 0xA. Making your program not work.

Comment: it is an option because these are two separate steps, you can for example erase the whole part, but then write pages separately.

Comment: why not just use the software as designed?

Comment: unlike a hard drive where the only sectors you want to affect are the ones you are writing to, with a microcontroller you may want to erase more sectors than the ones you are writing and/or in some rare/special cases you want to write on top of a section that you have already written on, making more zeros or ones depending on the erase state (erase to 0xFF is common but sometimes you will find erase to 0x00).

Comment: as a bare metal developer you own the whole chip/system generally, as an application programmer on some OS you own only the portion of the memory or disk space the OS allows you to have.

Comment: That explains everything, thanks!